# How to check if an argument from commandline has been set?

Tags: python

I can call my script like this:

```
python D:\myscript.py 60
```

And in the script I can do:

```
arg = sys.argv[1]
foo(arg)
```

But how could I test if the argument has been entered in the command line call? I need to do something like this:

```
if isset(sys.argv[1]):
    foo(sys.argv[1])
else:
    print "You must set argument!!!"
```

Comment: check if argv[1] is null, sorry i thought it was implicit that I was talking about argument 1.

Comment: @Jim `sys.argv` is not null, it contains at least the script's name as `sys.argv[0]`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Don't use `sys.argv` for handling the command-line interface; there's a module to do that: [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).

You can mark an argument as required by passing `required=True` to `add_argument`.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument("foo", ..., required=True)
parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: If needs are very simple, is there actually something *wrong* with using `sys.argv`?

Comment: @Jonik, not necessarily, but there's very rarely any reason _not_ to use it. Just as regexes are _very occasionally_ useful for parsing HTML, but there's very rarely any reason not to use an HTML parser.

Comment: -1 for providing an example that would not work in Richard's situation.
If `foo` is `60` then it will be a positional and you cannot add `required=True` to a positional.

Answer (score 75):

```py
import sys
len( sys.argv ) > 1
```

Answer (score 30):

```
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "You must set argument!!!"
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
   print('no arguments passed')
   sys.exit()
```

This will check if any arguments were passed at all. If there are no arguments, it will exit the script, without running the rest of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Note that there are already other answers that are very similar to this.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Python 2.7/3.2, use the [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module.  Otherwise, use the [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) module.  The module takes care of parsing the command-line, and you can check whether the number of positional arguments matches what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

This script uses the `IndexError` exception:

```
try:
    print(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    print("Empty argument")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for arg in sys.argv:
    print (arg)  
    #print cli arguments
```

You can use it to store the argument in list and used them. Is more safe way than to used them like this `sys.argv[n]`

No problems if no arguments are given

Answer (score 0):

I use [optparse module](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) for this but I guess because i am using 2.5 you can use argparse as Alex suggested if you are using 2.7 or greater

Answer (score -10):

`if(sys.argv[1]):` should work fine, if there are no arguments sys.argv[1] will be (should be) null

Comment: That will give an list index out of bounds error if that value is not set.

Comment: It will fall down with `IndexError`