# How can I fix urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I am trying to make a script that downloads a file, but it keeps getting the error `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>` after I do something like `download.py https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFuiz.png` Here is my script:

```py
import os
import wget
import sys
url = sys.argv[0]
directory = os.path.expanduser('~')
downloadFolderPath = r"%s\Downloads" % directory
os.chdir(downloadFolderPath)
url.replace(":", "%3A")
wget.download(url)
```

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: How do you call this script, what are the arguments?

Comment: @Lomtrur ```download.py https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFuiz.png``` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import wget
import sys
url = sys.argv[1]
directory = os.path.expanduser('~')
downloadFolderPath = os.path.join(directory, "Downloads")
os.chdir(downloadFolderPath)
url.replace(":", "%3A")
wget.download(url)
```

The problem is that you are using the first argument as the url. `argv[0]` is the script name, not the url you pass as an argument. See: [sys.argv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0]
>   is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a
>   full pathname or not).

Most likely you are getting the error because you are using Windows and the first argument is the full pathname, e.g. `c:\scripts\download.py` or the like.

If you change it to `sys.argv[1]` and call the script with

```
python download.py https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFuiz.png
```

(replace `download.py` with the name of your script) then it should work.

Note: I have also changed `downloadFolderPath`. By using `os.path.join()` the script should work independently of the operating system. On Ubuntu for example your version would not work because of the backslash in the path.

Comment: It worked when I did this, but do you know if it will work once I convert this to an exe?

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047110/is-it-possible-to-pass-arguments-to-a-python-made-exe-at-runtime) it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the command `download.py https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFuiz.png`, `sys.argv[0]` receives the value `download.py` and `sys.argv[1]` receives the value `https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFuiz.png`, so you should use argv[1] instead of argv[0]