# I want to create a .exe application to analyze some data from .csv files. My goal is to have a xlsx report. I don't know how to set the folder path

Tags: python, csv, exe

I want to build an .exe program to parse large .csv files much faster than I would manually in Excel.
The problem I encounter concerns the instructions to be given to the .exe to select and analyze the csv file. Once I move the program to another folder it doesn't work. How can I fix?

I set this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')
```

Comment: One option is to pass the file-path as an argument (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047110/is-it-possible-to-pass-arguments-to-a-python-made-exe-at-runtime))

Comment: If you are going to be making a .exe you will need a little bit more structure. Since it sounds like you have multiple files, you could make the user select the file/folder for themselves using a method such as https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-askopenfile-function-in-tkinter/ Or you could use a naming convention and have glob() find it https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-glob-function-to-find-files-recursively-in-python/. More scope might be needed to help you further.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.