# How to distinguish autostart of a program from opening it directly?

Tags: python, architecture, exe

My task is to launch the desktop cleaning program along with windows, but the interface (program settings) should only be launched when the program is opened directly (for example, through a shortcut).

I made a similar program device:
[image: ![I made a similar program device:]

But it has two entry points, so you have to create two separate exe, launcher and the script itself, but this solution seems crooked to me.

Is there a solution with one exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add command line parameter like `--disable-ui` (with corresponding processing in the application) and add it to the startup with this parameter. For example for Windows you can create a shortcut with target set to `"path_to_exe" --disable-ui` and add it to the startup folder ([see this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd))

Comment: Creating a shortcut with arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397125/reading-the-target-of-a-lnk-file-in-python/571573


Interception of arguments (from the command line or from a shortcut):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188467/how-to-check-if-an-argument-from-commandline-has-been-set/4188500